# Can I return back a gzipped JSON string inside an object I'm returning to the browser?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm struggling to find a way to send back JSON inside an object I'm returning (' running Coldfusion8' ) Currently I'm sending back this on `Ajax` request:

```
{
 "SUCCESS":true,
 "DATA": "JSON someData",
 "COUNT":10
 }
```

I also have content-only Ajax requests, where I'm just sending back the `DATA` part like so:

```
return "HTML someData"
```

This way I can send compressed and binary-gzipped HTML, which works nicely and reduces "payload" from 60k of data to 2-3k.

Since my page has to be available offline, I have started to do all markup enhancements on the client and only send JSON data from my database (I guess as it should be). However my JSON strings are far bigger than the inital HTML I was sending (say 10k JSON, that needs to be fiddled into elements I need to creat vs. 2-3k of ready to use snippets). So I'm punishing myself with extra bandwidth and client side processing.

To workaround, I started to try to gzip my JSON string (works) and whether I can send this back like in my 2nd example (doesn't work...):

```
return "JSON someData"
```

If I specifiy `text/JSON` in the return header as well as JSON in the `ajax-returnformat`, I'm getting only `Coldfusion` errors, telling me that `Unable to serialize binary data to JSON`

**QUestion**
Is it at all possible to send back JSON-gzipped? If so, what do I need to specifiy on my AJAX call (`returnformat`?) and server-side to make it work and not fail every time.

Thanks!

(NOTE: I would not ask, if I could set JSON GZIP encoding on the server!)

Comment: Enable HTTP Compression of Dynamic Content (IIS 7) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I'd follow Henry's approach and enable compression at the HTTP level. All browsers have excellent support for it. You can enable it through apache too. The app I work on has to support IIS and apache, so we used a compression filter that we configure in through ColdFusion's web.xml. It's been working a treat for years without any modification

Comment: @barnyr: yes, sounds good. I have gzip enabled for some file types (CSS,JS...), but everything dynamic is being sent back chunked-encoded only. As I cannot really access the server itself (my htaccess) being ignored, too, I ended up writing a Coldfusion wrapper, which compresses and gzips (if supported) all Ajax requests. Also works fine so far, but for the above, I was breaking my "routine" and was struggling to get it to work. Seems fine now. I also kinda like being "in control" of when to zip and not. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can "beat the returntype" by using:

```
<cfif variables.alredayBinary EQ "false">
    <cfcontent reset="no" variable="#CharsetDecode(passBackObject, "UTF-8")#" />
<cfelse>
    <cfcontent reset="no" variable="#passBackObject#" />    
</cfif>
<cfreturn  />
```

Returning nothing, because as I understand `<cfcontent>` goes straight back to the client. Maybe useful for someone else, too.